# Service unavailable error while building using Maven

Tags: maven, maven-2, m2eclipse, pom.xml

I am a newbie to Maven.
First time I run the `mvn clean install` command and it gave me the below error:

> [ERROR]     Non-resolvable parent POM: Could not transfer artifact
>   com.sybase365.mobiliser:mobiliser-parent:pom:4.6.0-RC02 from/to repo
>   (http://orinoco.sybase.com/nexus/content/groups/public-devel): Failed
>   to transfer file:
>   http://orinoco.sybase.com/nexus/content/groups/public-devel/com/sybase365/mobiliser/mobiliser-parent/4.6.0-RC02/mobiliser-parent-4.6.0-RC02.pom.
>   Return code is: 503, ReasonPhrase:Service Temporarily Unavailable. and
>   'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 3, column 11 ->

How do I resolve this error?

Comment: I have the same problem and believe it to be related to a proxy

Answer (score 3):

Your remote repository is inaccessible.  See explanation for error 503 in [here](http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E503.html).

Comment: Could you update the link? It doesn't refer to a page about 503

Answer (score 3):

I think i found the reason it gives 503. In my case this was a proxy issues inspite of excluding hosts that belong to a certain domain.

Remove the proxy from manage jenkins -> manage plugin -> advanced  and try again

Answer (score 2):

Could be, also I find this error happens all the time when the repo is available and downloading the file manually from the nexus GUI works.  For some reason maven looks in the wrong repository location.  If it happens for one jar and its pom you can down load the file by hand.

If maven ever hits a temporary HTTP problem it stores a lastUpdated file that you need to delete or it will not try to download the file again for a while.
sudo updatedb && locate lastUpdated | xargs rm
Or scrabble around in explorer in /Users/username/.m2/repository to find the files if you use windoze

Another thing that can mess with repo access is the proxy that maven uses. Check the contents of ~/.m2/settings.xml or create this file and setup what ever HTTP proxies or lack there of that you need to access the repos you have configured in poms.